# C How to make a list of messages?

Tags: c, list

I would like to make a list of messages witch I call by an index number. So I would get the input 13, then message 13 should be printed. My issue is that I need a lot of theses messages and they need to be of multiple lines, this would take up to much space in my main file. So my question is how do I store all these messages and call them when needed?

Comment: Though probably overkill for your needs, POSIX message catalogs would be one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would store them in a separate source file in an array of `char*`. The number can simply be an index into the array.

Comment: `char**` is probably more appropriate: one `char*` for each message.

Comment: Yes, by `char *` array, I meant an array of `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding of your question. You should use array of string. because array is the fastest way of storing and retrieving data. you may use like below:

```
char a[2][1000];
strcpy(a[0], "I hello how r u");
strcpy(a[1], "i m fine");
```

You can access messages by index of array. if you want access first message then you will get by a[0],for second message a[1], for third a[2] and so on.

Comment: You could initialize `a` with those strings instead of doing `strcpy()` manually, though.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach

```
char const * getMessageByIndex( int const index ) {

    static char const * const messages[] = {
        "I am message 0",
        "I am message 1",
        // ...
    };

    int const numMessages = sizeof messages / sizeof messages[ 0 ];
    if( (index < 0) || (numMessages <= index) {
        // error handling
        return "index out of bound";
    }

    return messages[ index ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make index file and message file. and message read by index file.

e.g.)*Error handling is omitted.

make index and message file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* message[] = {
    "1st message",
    "2nd message\ninclude newline",
    "3rd message"
    //...
};

int main(){
    FILE *indexFile, *textFile;
    long loc=0;
    int i, size, len;

    size=sizeof(message)/sizeof(char*);
    indexFile=fopen("index.dat", "wb");
    textFile=fopen("message.dat", "wb");

    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        loc = ftell(textFile);
        fwrite(message[i], sizeof(char), len=strlen(message[i]), textFile);
        fwrite(&loc, sizeof(long), 1, indexFile);
        fwrite(&len, sizeof(int),  1, indexFile);
    }

    fclose(textFile);
    fclose(indexFile);
    return 0;
}
```

use sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* readMessage(int n){
    char *message;
    FILE *indexFile, *textFile;
    long loc;
    int i, size, len;
    int recordSize = sizeof(long) + sizeof(int);

    indexFile=fopen("index.dat", "rb");
    textFile=fopen("message.dat", "rb");

    loc = recordSize * n;
    fseek(indexFile, loc, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&loc, sizeof(long), 1, indexFile);
    fread(&len, sizeof(int ), 1, indexFile);
    message=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    fseek(textFile, loc, SEEK_SET);
    fread(message, sizeof(char), len, textFile);
    message[len]='\0';

    fclose(textFile);
    fclose(indexFile);
    return message;
}

int main(){
    char *mes;
    int n;
    n =1;
    mes = readMessage(n);//zero origin
    printf("message %d is \"%s\"\n", n, mes);
    free(mes);

    return 0;
}
```